# How do I return a subcollection using StreamProvider? [Flutter, Firebase]

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I followed TheNetNinja's Flutter and Firebase tutorial but now I'm trying to display information from a subcollection.

[image: here's my firebase]

[image]

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Food>>.value(
      initialData: [],
      value: DatabaseService().food,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: FoodList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

^menu.dart

```
class FoodList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodListState createState() => _FoodListState();
}

class _FoodListState extends State<FoodList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final food = Provider.of<List<Food>>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: food.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return FoodTile(food: food[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

^food_list.dart

```
class FoodTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Food food;
  FoodTile({this.food});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return foodInfoCard(context, Icons.person_outline, 'Name', food.name);
  }

  Card foodInfoCard(
      BuildContext context, IconData icon, String title, String subtitle) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 6, 20, 0),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(icon),
        title: Text(title),
        subtitle: Text(subtitle),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

^food_tile.dart

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  final CollectionReference restaurantCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurant');
  List<Food> _foodListFromSS(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Food(
        name: doc.data()['name'] ?? '',
        description: doc.data()['description'] ?? '',
        oriPrice: doc.data()['oriPrice'] ?? 0.0,
        salePrice: doc.data()['salePrice'] ?? 0.0,
        pax: doc.data()['pax'] ?? 0,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<Food>> get food {
    return restaurantCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('food')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_foodListFromSS);
  }
}
```

^database.dart

[image: Menu screen where i want to display the listiles]

I've been searching for solutions but most of them are streambuilder and not streamproviders. I've done most of it using streamproviders, so idrk how to change it. Can anyone help me? :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the `uid` to the `DatabaseService` constructor in the `Menu` widget.

This:

```dart
      value: DatabaseService().food,
```

should change to:

```dart
      value: DatabaseService(uid).food,
```

Also, since the `uid` is a required parameter for the `DatabaseService`, you can mark it as `@required` so the analyzer can show a hint to pass that parameter. See below:

```dart
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({@required this.uid}); //Added the @required annotation here

  ...
}
```

Comment: You are possibly getting an empty list because your initial data is set to an empty list.
Put a breakpoint on `snapshot.docs` in the `_foodListFromSS` filter method and see if it shows anything.

Comment: apologies for the inconvenience. what you replied in the answers worked flawless. I just realised the parameters to connect with firebase were not similar. however, i thank you for your help! but i have another question regarding initialData, other than [], what else can i put in? i was so lost when i first saw initialData..

Comment: If you have some previous data saved or some default data to show the user, you can put that in `initialData` so it shows up while it fetches the data from the stream provided to `value` in the `StreamProvider`.

Comment: i seee.. so if it's a list, i can set the initalData as an empty list. but what if it's not a list, it's just a single object. what can i return?

Comment: You can return a default object if you have one or you could not give it a value. When you don't give it a value, that means `final food = Provider.of<List<Food>>(context);` will be null while it's fetching the data, so you can add a null check to know when to display/use the data like `if (food == null) {return CircularProgressIndicator();} else {return Widget();}`.

Comment: ohhh okieee cool... thanks for the explanation! i have a better understanding of this now.